# Why do I have to specify namespace when choosing startup form?

Tags: c#

I wasn't able to set my new form as a startup form, it complained about it not existing.
But after some minutes I tried with typing "Namespace.NewForm" and that worked.

In my other project, The startup is set as this:

```
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Why did I have to specify namespace when changing startup form in this project?

Comment: This means the namespace that MyForm is contained within is different then the namespace Program is contained within.  In other words it normally would not be required, and by default a WinForm project would do place both in the same namespace.

Comment: You rock, that was it, forgot to check that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a using directive so you do not have to fully qualify the types within the namespace in question.

```
using MyNameSpace;
```

It's also worth pointing out that using directives in C# do not give you access to namespaces nested in the namespace you specify (just in case you are wondering). This means that

```
using System;
```

does not give you access to `System.IO`

Answer (score 4):

Presumably because you didn't have a `using` directive for it:

```
using SomeNamespace;

...

Application.Run(new SomeForm());
```

There's nothing particularly different about the code used to call `Application.Run` - it's just normal C# code, following the normal rules of C#.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's more context here than you're sharing.  Regardless of what you're doing, any place where you reference `MyForm` will need to be able to resolve that reference to a fully-qualified class (including namespace).  This means that it will either need to be fully-qualified or it will need its namespace included in the `using` statements at the top of the file (and be unambiguous).

Does your "working" version already have the `using` directive and the "non-working" version simply does not?  Do your versions attempt to set the startup form in different places?

I suspect that the "working" version has the `using` directive already in place and that, for whatever reason, it's not in place in the "non-working" version.